# If statment in return inside a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, dom

I have a problem. If I press the plus button (fas fa-plus) inside of a pop-up, the component `<Avatar>` showes up. As soon as i close the `<Avatar`> component it disapears but i can't open it again. I think the problem relies on the following line: `{popupClicked === true && <Avtar> }` but i cant find the solution to my problem. Maybe you guys can help me out. I just want to reuse the `<Avatar>`component, so a user can update his profilepicture in a application.

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM, { render } from "react-dom";
import Avatar from "react-avatar-edit";
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';

const Profilpic = () => {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
  const [popupClicked, setPopupClicked] = useState(false);

  const onClose = async () => {
    setPopupClicked(false);
  };

  const onCrop = (preview) => {
    setPreview(preview);
  };

  const handleClick = () =>{
    setPopupClicked(!popupClicked);
    console.log(popupClicked);
  }



  const onBeforeFileLoad = (elem) => {
    if (elem.target.files[0].size > 512000) {
      alert("Hoppla, deine Bilddateigröße ist etwas zu groß!");
      elem.target.value = "";
    }
    else {
      //ToDO
      //richtiges Foto erhalten und auch abspeichern
      console.log(elem.target.files[0])
      setSrc(elem)
    }
  };

 


  return (
    <div>
    <Popup trigger={ preview ? <img src={preview} alt="Preview" width="150px" height="150px"/> :  <i className="far fa-user-circle"></i>} position="right center" >
    {close => (
      <div>
         <i class="fas fa-plus" onClick={handleClick}></i>  
      </div>
    )}
  </Popup>
  {popupClicked === true &&

    <Avatar
       width={300}
       height={300}
       onCrop={onCrop}
       onClose={onClose}
       onBeforeFileLoad={onBeforeFileLoad}
       src={src}
       label="Klicke für ein Foto von dir "
     />

  }
  </div>
    
      
     
    
  );
}

export default Profilpic;
```

Comment: Could try: `setPopupClicked(oldValue => !oldValue);`

Comment: @DavinTryon the popupClicked is changing but unfortunatelly it has no effect on the showing of the <Avatar> component :(

Comment: Why is your `fa-plus` div inserted as a function?

Comment: Because use a library and it works like that https://github.com/yjose/reactjs-popup